# How to prevent value out of range for a double-precision float?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, tensorflow, type-conversion

I have a large dataframe that will be regularly updated and then converted to a tensorflow dataset. The dataframe may be updated with values exceeding the range of a [double precision float](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-big-sql/5.0.4?topic=list-numbers) but tensorflow can't convert these values. I need a way to round all the out of range values to within range.

Using the code:

```
test_data_x = test_data_x.astype(float)
test_dataset_x = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(test_data_x.to_dict(orient="list"))
```

produces the error "Can't convert Python sequence with a value out of range for a double-precision float."

Is there a way to convert my data so that all the values are made to be in range?

Comment: what is your `test_data_x` originally? If I do `test_data_x = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(20).reshape(4,5))`, and then your code, there are no errors.

Comment: clarified that my data is the source of the error, I need to know how to find and round the out of range values

Comment: I'm confused how the `OverflowError` doesn't occur on the line `test_data_x = test_data_x.astype(float)`. What does `test_data_x.dtypes` show originally? Are you storing integers of floats?

Answer (score 0):

##### Reproducible example:

It's weird. The numbers don't even have to exceed the `float64` maximum value!

```py
max_f32 = np.finfo('float32').max

df = pd.DataFrame([[max_f32, max_f32 * 2], [max_f32, max_f32 * 2]])
print(df.dtypes)
```

|  | 0 |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | float32 |
| 1 | float64 |

```py
tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(df.to_dict(orient="list"))
```

> ValueError: Can't convert Python sequence with a value out of range for a double-precision float.

---

It works, however, if the `float64` value is not so large:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([[max_f32, max_f32 + (max_f32/2**30)], [max_f32, max_f32 + 2*100]])
```